# Toggle and the jQuery UI button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to give my users the option to use one of two kind of editors:

- HTML Editor
- MCE Editor

I can handle the coding of this when it comes to selecting the editor and making that work.  But I am having problems with the UI side. At first I gave the users a checkbox but now I am thinking a better way would be to use the jQuery UI button and toggle this to show either the text "HTML Editor" or "MCE Editor". Has anyone coded anything similar to this? I have looked at the documentation for button but it's still not clear to me how I could toggle between two states.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have a button with an id of `toggleButton` in your HTML.

```
var isMCE = false;

$("#toggleButton").click(function() {
    if(isMCE) {
        // change your editor back to normal here
        isMCE = false;
    } else {
        // change your editor to MCE here
        isMCE = true;
    }
});
```

`toggle()`, as per [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), simply toggles the visibility of an element and wouldn't suit your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $( "#controls #html" ).button({
                text: 'Edit',
                })
                .click(function() {
                     var btn = $("#controls #html");
                     btn.button('option', 'text', 'MCE');
                     if (btn[0].checked) {
                           btn.button('option', 'text', 'HTML');
                           doMCE();
                     } else { 
                           btn.button('option', 'text', 'MCE');
                           doHTML();
                     }
                });

    <div id="controls">
         <input type="checkbox" id="html" name="html"><label for="html"></label>
    </div>
```